# Backpack CRUD categories select field

Tags: arrays, laravel-5, crud, laravel-backpack

I have some trouble here. I use Backpack CRUD generator for my admin panel. In the database (categories column) I have a "parent_id" field which specify which is parent and children. The addFiled of CRUD has a type "select_from_array" which accept an array ( 'value'=>'name'). And I don't know how to make an array which something like that from the array I got from DB toArray(). Tks alot.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an associative array of Product names, with the IDs as keys, you would do this:

```
Product::all()->keyBy('id')->pluck('name')->toArray()
```

Hope it helps.